# Libgdx reload scene2d skin after application hidden

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having an issue with libgdx skin.

When the app is paused or goes into the background and then reopens all my scene2d textures are just showing up black. I assume that the underlying textures need to be reloaded.

I'm creating my skin using the following code

```
FileHandle jsonFile = Gdx.files.internal( "ui/uiskin.json" );
FileHandle atlasFile = Gdx.files.internal( "ui/uiskin.atlas" );
TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(atlasFile);
skin = new Skin(jsonFile, atlas);
```

My question is if there any way that I can detect when the texture needs to be reloaded and how to best do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that it is best to rebuild the skin when you reopen your app.

Comment: But how does this work when I have the skin applied to various objects?